# Display rows with current date as top result using react-table

Tags: reactjs, date, sorting, react-table

I'm trying to create a table using [react-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/) that would display data that matches today's date as the top result. For instance, today is 18 August 2021, so I would like any data entry that matches 08/18/2021 (***mm/dd/yyyy*** format) to be displayed as the topmost entry in my table.

[My current table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNGgn.png)

To give an example, I have already sorted my table in chronological order (from earliest to latest in ***mm/dd/yyyy*** format). However, I want any entry/entries in the table above with today's date (eg. `Date of Operation: 08/18/2021`) to be displayed at the top of the table. Thereafter, entries that do not match today's date will continue to be sorted in chronological order.

Can someone please let me know how this can be done? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the code details, you should be able to do this by supplying a custom sort function in the column definition [API docs](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useSortBy). We don't do this specific sort but we do have multiple custom sort functions, and I got the most help in writing them by reading the [sortTypes.js file](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/src/sortTypes.js) from the library source.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is it possible to get some guidance in how the code for this custom sort would look like? Perhaps a pseudocode would be very helpful. 

I have thought about this, and if I am not mistaken, simply comparing data entries with the current date would not work, because this prevents me from sorting non-current date entries in a chronological order. I am taking reference from the datetime function implementation in the sortTypes.js file you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple date sort function. You basically get two rows and a columnId and return -1, 0, or 1.

```
    const prevDate = new Date(prev.original[columnId])
    const prevIsDate = ...
    const currDate = new Date(curr.original[columnId])
    const currIsDate = ...
    if (prevIsDate && currIsDate) {
      return prevDate > currDate ? 1 : -1
    } else {
      if (!prevIsDate) {
        return !currIsDate ? 0 : 1
      } else {
        return 1
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have tried this implementation but it does not seem to work.. Using your code, the table is only sorted in chronological order, but entries with today's date were not bumped up to the top (https://imgur.com/a/ojvRuTL). Could you explain a little bit more what prevIsDate and currIsDate refers to? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: It wasn't intended to be a complete solution for you, just show you how I implemented something similar. You need to rewrite to base the return value on your requirement.